# C#: How to assign random int values to variables?

Tags: c#, arrays, variables, random, save

I have made a dice class that includes a method which uses random.next to determine a random int value from 1-6.

`Fairdice.cs`:

```
 class FairDice
{

    //defining variable and property
    private Random rnd;
    public int Current { get; private set; }
    public FairDice()
    {
        rnd = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
        Current = 0;
    }

    public int FRoll()
    {
        Current = rnd.Next(1, 7);
        return Current;
    }
```

`RollDice.cs` that features a loop for printing.

```
static class RollDice
{
    public static void Roll(this int count, Action action)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
           action();
        }
    }
}
```

`Program.cs` includes this code, which prints out 5 random values between 1-6:

```
FairDice fd = new FairDice();
                    5.Roll(() => Console.WriteLine("Dice: " + fd.FRoll()));
```

Problem: I wish to assign the random values in each variable and store and save them in either a list or array for future use.

clarification:

lets say it prints out the numbers: `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` - i then wish to assign each value a variable: `a = 1, b = 2, ... f = 5`.

and/or simply store the values in an array `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What you mean "in each variable"?

Comment: lets say it prints out the numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 - i wish to assign each value a variable:

a = 1,

b = 2,
...

f = 5.

@ozsh83

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the values returned by calling `FRoll` then you could do something like this:

```
FairDice fd = new FairDice();
var numbers = new List<int>();
5.Roll(() => numbers.Add(fd.FRoll()));  // Append the values to the list as we generate them
var firstNumberRolled = numbers[0]; // Access the values later
Console.WriteLine($"The first number rolled was {firstNumberRolled}");
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the throw results are into an array you can extract assign variables as necessary.

```
class FairDice
{
    private static int _seed;
    private static ThreadLocal<Random> threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<Random>
        (() => new Random(Interlocked.Increment(ref _seed)));

    static FairDice()
    {
        _seed = Environment.TickCount;
    }

    private static Random Rng { get { return threadLocal.Value; } }

    public int Roll()
    {
        return Rng.Next(1, 6);
    }
}

static class RollDice
{
    public static int[] Roll(this int count, FairDice dice)
    {
        int[] values = new int[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            values[i] = dice.Roll();
        }
        return values;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FairDice fd = new FairDice();
        int[] values = 5.Roll(fd);
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", values.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray()));
    }
}
```

Comment: It works as intended, thank you.

However, I do have a hard time grasping the FairDice class you made. Do you care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

add this to FairDice (lines with '*'):

```
class FairDice
*         private int[] returnedValues;
public int FRoll()
        {
            Current = rnd.Next(1, 7);
*            returnedValues[Current]++;
            return Current;
        }

*public void GetreturnedValues()
*        {
*            for (int i = 1; i < 7; i++)
*            {
*                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, returnedValues[i]);
*            }
*        }
```

After this adding `d.GetreturnedValues();` to you Program.cs will show how many time the different values where thrown.